# Translate Object position into Time

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, mathematics

I have a cube which i am moving in circle shape (with horizontal key input) is below code suggested.

```
public class Oscillator : MonoBehaviour {
    float timeCounter = 0;

    float speed,width, height;

    public float yPosition = 30;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        speed = 2; width = 10; height = 10;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        timeCounter += Time.deltaTime * speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float x = Mathf.Sin (timeCounter)* height; 
        float y = yPosition;
        float z = Mathf.Cos (timeCounter) * width;
        transform.position = new Vector3 (x, y, z);

    }
}
```

Now my object is moving  in circular shape which is fine. Now i want to translate my objects movement into time.
Let suppose

if my object x position is 1 then it should give me time 1.0

if it is 1.5 then it should give me 1.5

it increase or decrease according to x postion of my object (or possibly throught z).

**I logged my object's x position which is starting from 0 to 9.999 and then become decrease 0, then -1 to -9 then it become decrease 0 and reached to its initial position**. This circular movement x values are strange for me, i am unable to form any formula that can convert my x position into time.
Please can any one help me in this purely mathematics and 3d math problem?

Comment: You already have a timeCounter field. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: No man, i want that is another thing.

Comment: So are you wanting to know how fast your moving, or provide movement as a value of units per time? This question is unclear, and it shows no research effort.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the timestamp at which your object will reach a particular spot on its circular path?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments i have manage to do this using my answer.

Comment: But it has some problem which i am trying to solve. if you can improve it then please do it. I want to convert one range of number to another range

Answer (score 0):

I am able to convert my range

> 0 to 9.999 and then become decrease 0, then -1 to -9 then it become
>   decrease 0 and reached to its initial position

Into time using this code snippet. Thanks to this [**stackoverflow answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229711/4190853).

```
public float ConvertRange(float originalStart, float orignialEnd, float newStart, float newEnd, float value){
        double scale = (newEnd - newStart) / (orignialEnd - originalStart);
        return (float) (newStart + ((value - originalStart) * scale));
    }
```

I am calling CovertRange Method using these parameters.

```
hour = ConvertRange(-9.99f,9.99f, 0f, 23.99f, controlledCube.transform.position.x);
```

while variables means

```
     int originalStart, int originalEnd, // original range, my object position of any axis
    int newStart, int newEnd, // desired range
    int value) // value to convert
```

***Note : This is not a complete  answer. It somehow changing one range to another range but partially not completely.***